# Remove payment information from iOS

Tags: ipad, ios

I had connected my iPad mini to my net-safe card which creates a virtual debit card and lasts for 48 hours and automatically gets void after that for security purpose. But now I want to remove that information because the virtual card has expired but I am compelled to put some information. It does not have "none" option in payment method which most of the people say that it has. It is related to country?

Comment: I assume you are referring to the payment instructions in the iTunes store?

Comment: yes.. And I just checked with my bank accounts. The deductions were not appropriate. I had purchased apps of some thing around 400 rps but only 40 rps were deducted. So for further deduction they might be forcing me to put the information.

Comment: From my experiences, deductions in the Indian Store move slower than the US store. It takes 72 hours (3 days) for the next batch of purchases to be processed. As virtual debit cards usually last only 24-48 hours, it is not advisable to use them in the Indian Store.

Comment: @duci9y : yes but my bank is forcing to use virtual card. I dont have any other option. How do I atleast pay the money for apps which I have already bought

Answer (score 1):

Finally got it.

As per @duci9y it takes approximately 3 days to complete transaction.
Since my transaction wasn't complete, apple was forcing me to put my credit card details. When I put my credit card details the appropriate amount was deducted and then the option "none" was visible.